# Unable to import com.firebase.ui.auth.ResultCodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to import the namespace as shown below, but getting an error when I get to ResultCodes. I am using Android Studio version 3.2 and I have successfully added Firebase to my Android project.

```
import com.firebase.ui.auth.ResultCodes;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this commit](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/commit/fba3335e6c4e9aa279ac45f370ee3c3936aa3db3), the `ResultCodes` class has been removed, in favour of using `Activity` and `ErrorCodes` instead:

- `Activity.RESULT_OK` replaces `ResultCodes.OK`
- `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` replaces `ResultCodes.CANCELLED`
- `ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK` replaces `ResultCodes.NO_NETWORK`
- `ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR` replaces `ResultCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR`

More information on using these codes can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#response-codes).